# How to control selection of items in Django's QuerySet in html template?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-queryset

I need 2 buttons that would control which item from QuerySet should be displayed as a part of a video player to change playlist videos back and forth (all other features are done and good).

In views.py I have function that sends QuerySet through "video.objects.all()" and I can select any item in HTML template by calling like "videos.all.1.video.url". But IDs are hardcoded and for loop doesn't seem to be fitting here. So I'm stuck on how and where to control items by IDs. Should be html (java?) or in Django's views.py?

Some pointing in the right direction would help.

views.py:

```
@login_required
def userfunc(request):

    videos = Video.objects.all()
    
    return render(request, 'myapp/myhtml.html', {'videos':videos})
```

myhtml.html:

```
<div class="player">

  <video class="player__video viewer" src="{{ videos.all.1.video.url }}"></video>

  <div class="player__central">
    <center>
    <button class="player__button toggle" title="Play">►</button>
    </center>
  </div>

  <div class="player__controls">
    <button class="player__button previous_vid">❚◀</button>
    <button class="player__button next_vid">►❚</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think we might need to see something from your views.py and html template. Is the [first filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#first) what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi @powlo, just added the code. Not sure if first filter would help me here. I want to update video src based on clicked next or previous button. So if I start with "videos.all.1.video.url" and I click on next video, I would like to update it by "videos.all.2.video.url".

Comment: Ah, if you want to stay on the same page then you'll need some javascript to do that. The [json_script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) filter will help move data from the django template to the js world.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will try that.